# How can i use AWS ECS to run tests which in turn create containers for testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, containers, amazon-ecs

I got this tutorial which explains how to use ECS to run jenkins master and slave on ECS

https://tech.ticketfly.com/our-journey-to-continuous-delivery-chapter-4-run-jenkins-infrastructure-on-aws-container-service-ef37e0304b95

Its working fine but my issue is , My tests require first  use docker compose to build  containers and then run tests inside them . is there any way i can use jenkins where it first create separate ECS services and then run tests?

I was using buildkite before where Agents run on ec2 task  and they craete containers before every test and then destroy but now i want to shift eveything on ECS.

Any ideas

Comment: Instead of creating AWS ECS task and other stuff write a simple bash script which create an image and run container after test pass kill the container to avoid consuming resource this is what we do for our project. run that script from jenkins.